# Im trying to create element by clicking button with position of moving existing element but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, positioning, createelement

```
var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
function shot() {
var arrows = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(arrows);
arrows.style.backgroundColor = "black";
arrows.style.height = "80" + "px";
arrows.style.width = "3" + "px";
var arrowX = parseInt(document.arrow.style.left);
var arrowY = parseInt(document.arrow.style.top);
document.arrows.style.left = arrowX + "px"; 
document.arrows.style.top = arrowY + "px";
};
```

When I run it and click button which runs function shot it says it cannot read property "style" of undefined. It also spawns a new element on position it would spawn without any position defining.
Yep, my ids are correct.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="arrow"><div>
<button id="button" onclick="shot();"> Shot! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#arrow {
background-color: black;
height: 80px;
width: 1.5px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
```

Here is full project JS, which u dont need. Its not complete. There is button faster but it doesnt work, idk why. It should be archery game

```
var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
var arrowPos = -50;
var speed = 1000;
var speed2 = speed/100;
function arrow_move_right() {

arrowPos += 1;
arrow.style.left = arrowPos + "px";
if (arrowPos >= 280) {
    return arrow_move_left()
}
else {
setTimeout(arrow_move_right, speed2);
};
};
function arrow_move_left() {
arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
arrowPos -= 1;
arrow.style.left = arrowPos + "px";
if (arrowPos <= -50) {
    return arrow_move_right()
}
setTimeout(arrow_move_left, speed2);
};
function faster() {
speed -= 100;
alert(speed)
}

function shot() {
var arrows = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(arrows);
arrows.style.backgroundColor = "black";
arrows.style.height = "80" + "px";
arrows.style.width = "1.5" + "px";
var arrowX = parseInt(arrow.style.left);
var arrowY = parseInt(arrow.style.top);
alert(arrowX);
alert(arrowY);
// arrows.style.left = arrowX; 
// arrows.style.top = arrowY;
arrows.style.pos = "relative";
arrows.style.top = -50 + "px";
};
```

Comment: What is `document.arrow` ? It is the undefined element

Comment: Do you mean only arrow?

Comment: Arrow is var storing element I got with getElementById

Comment: use only `arrow` instead of `document.arrow` And `arrows` instead of `document.arrows`

Comment: Now it says it cannot get style of null instead of undefined...

Comment: Check my answer. Its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for!

```js
var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
function shot() {
    var arrows = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(arrows);
    arrows.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    arrows.style.height = "80px";
    arrows.style.width = "3px";
    arrows.style.position = "absolute";
    arrows.style.top = arrow.offsetTop + "px";
    arrows.style.left = arrow.offsetLeft + "px";
};
```

```css
#arrow {
    height: 80px;
    width: 3px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: move 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: move 5s infinite;
}

/* Styles for animating arrow */
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 400px;}
}

@keyframes move {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 400px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow"></div>
<button id="button" onclick="shot();"> Shot! </button>
```

Comment: No, it should create elements on the same position as element "arrow"

Comment: The above snippet creates element at the same position as element "arrow". If that is not what you want, you can explain exactly what should happen when you click on "Shot!" button.

Comment: I need it to create element on the current position of arrow because IT will be moving. So it should find out position of arrow and create element on it

Comment: 1. It doesnt work. It shows it cannot read property offsettop of null. 2. I have my moving animation. I just need the creating element thing

Comment: Will it be possible for you to post a snippet of your animation or a link to it? Because the above code snippet works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean....

```js
var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
function shot() {
var arrows = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(arrows);
arrows.style.backgroundColor = "black";
arrows.style.height = "80" + "px";
arrows.style.width = "3" + "px";
var arrowX = parseInt(arrow.style.left);
var arrowY = parseInt(arrow.style.top);
arrows.style.left = arrowX + "px"; 
arrows.style.top = arrowY + "px";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="arrow"><div>
<button id="button" onclick="shot();"> Shot! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No it is not? Paste your full code.. You must have done something other than this. As it is working here